# How to Embed Power App Widget in a Website?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

## Problem Statement:

1. We need to make a reusable PowerApp widget which we can embed in multiple partner websites.
2. Requirement is to provide a Workflow to the all partners which can be embeded in their websites.

## Query:

> Is there a way to achieve this i.e. embed a Power App Widgit which can be embedded in any Website without disturbing the existing functionality of the websites?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/embed-apps-dev#embed-your-app-in-a-website)

> Embedding your app is now as simple as adding the iframe to the HTML code for your site (or any other service that supports iframes, such as Power BI or SharePoint):
>
> `<iframe width="[W]" height="[H]" src="https://apps.powerapps.com/play/[AppID]?source=website&screenColor=rgba(165,34,55,1)" allow="geolocation; microphone; camera"/>`

But you will face challenges in signin.

> - If your website uses Azure Active Directory (AAD) based authentication, no additional sign-in is required.
> - If your website uses any other sign-in mechanism or is not authenticated, your users see a sign-in prompt on the iframe. After they sign-in, they will be able to run the app as long as the author of the app has shared it with them.

Comment: I tried this method, but getting below error

This app isn't working. Refresh your browser or try again later.